# How do I get an HTML comment with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

If I have that

```
  <!-- some comment -->
```

How do I get this element and change the content with javascript?
And if I have a code inside that and I want to delete the tag of comments how can I do it?

Comment: He want to get the dom element, which the comment is

Comment: Related - [Is it possible to get reference to comment element/block by JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6027830/104380)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### Using a NodeIterator (IE >= 9)

The best method is to use a dedicated [NodeIterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator) instance iterating all comments contained in a given root element.

[See it in action!](http://jsfiddle.net/yjkmxmtt/3/)

```
function filterNone() {
    return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
}

function getAllComments(rootElem) {
    var comments = [];
    // Fourth argument, which is actually obsolete according to the DOM4 standard, is required in IE 11
    var iterator = document.createNodeIterator(rootElem, NodeFilter.SHOW_COMMENT, filterNone, false);
    var curNode;
    while (curNode = iterator.nextNode()) {
        comments.push(curNode.nodeValue);
    }
    return comments;
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    console.log(getAllComments(document.body));
});
```

### Using a custom-made DOM traversal (to support IE < 9 as well)

If you have to support older browsers (e.g. IE <9), you need to traverse the DOM yourself and extract those elements whose [node type](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) is [`Node.COMMENT_NODE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Comment).

[See it in action!](http://jsfiddle.net/7UXum/77/)

```
// Thanks to Yoshi for the hint!
// Polyfill for IE < 9
if (!Node) {
    var Node = {};
}
if (!Node.COMMENT_NODE) {
    // numeric value according to the DOM spec
    Node.COMMENT_NODE = 8;
}

function getComments(elem) {
  var children = elem.childNodes;
  var comments = [];

  for (var i=0, len=children.length; i<len; i++) {
    if (children[i].nodeType == Node.COMMENT_NODE) {
      comments.push(children[i]);
    }
  }
  return comments;
}
```

### Extracting a node's contents and delete it

Independent of the way you choose from above, you receive the same node DOM objects.

Accessing a comment's contents is as easy as `commentObject.nodeValue`.
Deleting a comment is a bit more verbose: `commentObject.parentNode.removeChild(commentObject)`

Comment: word of warning, the Node-constants are not available in IE<9

Comment: Also see deep traversal method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027830/is-it-possible-to-get-reference-to-comment-element-block-by-javascript

Answer (score 5):

You have to travers the DOM to get it.
The `nodeType` of the comment DOM element is `8`

```
if( oNode.nodeType === 8 ) {
  oNode.parentNode.removeChild( oNode );
}
```

would be an approach

Answer (score 1):

Here is a JQuery plugin that retrieves the comments:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1563-jQuery-Comments-Plug-in-To-Access-HTML-Comments-For-DOM-Templating.htm

The basic idea is to look at `nodes`, not `elements`:

http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_nodes.asp

You start with `document` object, and iterate through them using `childNodes` collection. You have to check for `node.nodeType == 8` which will return just the comment nodes (note that you need to iterate through child nodes recursively).

Comment: There is no way to do it without Jquery? I want to know how to do it with pure javascript

Comment: There's no such thing as something that jQuery can do that pure JavaScript cannot do. jQuery does not add anything to the browser's JavaScript engine; it's just a utility library that abstracts what's already there.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to store a template for an entire web page. But the <template>-tag cannot contain for example an <html>-tag. So I decided to store my template inside an HTML-comment instead.

I put the HTML-comment in a hidden <div> in order to more easily retrieve the text in that specific HTML-comment, and not have to bother with distinguishing it from other HTML-comments.

Here is a demo of how you can retrieve what's inside a HTML-comment by using createTreeWalker.

```js
alert(
  document.createTreeWalker(
    document.getElementById('commentDiv'), 
    NodeFilter.SHOW_COMMENT, 
    null, 
    false
  ).nextNode().nodeValue
);
```

```html
<p>Getting the text in a HTML-comment.</p>
<p>I use createTreeWalker to make sure we don't simply capture an empty text node by mistake. You could make the code even simpler, but then you must make sure that the &lt;div>-tag is immediately followed by the "&lt;!--", like this "&lt;div>&lt;!--". But if that breaks because of for example autoformating in an editor, so that you get a line feed in between or so, then the simpler method will fail. That is why I prefere to use the createTreeWalker here.</p>
<!--
  This is NOT the comment we want to get text from
-->
<div id="commentDiv" style="display:none;">
  <!--
    This is THE text, and you can have anything in here
    <>
    <div>
    <script>alert('hello');</script>
    etc.
    except of course an end of HTML-comment.

    An advantage of this way to store a template compared to using
    the <template>-tag, is that the <template>-tag can for example
    not contain a <html>-tag, in case you need to have a template
    for an entire web page.

    Check also my explanation down in the body text for why I use 
    createTreeWalker instead of some simpler code.
  -->
</div>
<!--
  This is also NOT the comment we want to get text from
-->
<p>End of body.</p>
```