# How can I select an element in Javascript, that has added to html and in html has commented

Tags: javascript

I want select an element that has commented in HTML and I add it in JavaScript to HTML, but when I did I got null error

```
const deleteElement=document.querySelector('.workout__delete');
```

`workout__delete` class that added to div, has commented in HTML and I added div to html through JavaScript, but I got null error from `deleteElement`.

Comment: Appreciate that you have a problem to solve. But you must help use help you. Your question is difficult to understand, so showing the HTML that you describe would be helpful. You can use [StackSnippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get an HTML comment with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363946/how-do-i-get-an-html-comment-with-javascript)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.