# How to get html code comments in a page by javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get value of html Code comments with javascript. 
For example:

```
<code data-type="tb-datalazyload" id="frslistCodeArea">
    <!-- <li class="j_thread_list clearfix"></li>--> 
</code>
```

I want to get the `<li class="j_thread_list clearfix"></li>`.

---

I execute it in chrome. why? who can help me?

[image]

Comment: Just as <!-- xxx --> in html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get reference to comment element/block by JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027830/is-it-possible-to-get-reference-to-comment-element-block-by-javascript)

Comment: Heard,yes this is called a "comment" - will be easier to look it up when referred to as such

Comment: @Djizeus But when i execute" document.getElementsByTagName("code")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue ", I can get nothing but "". why?

Comment: Walk the DOM looking for nodes of type comment.

Comment: I execute "document.getElementsByTagName("code")[0].childNodes[0].nodeType", It returns 8

Comment: The code works: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/tcWdy/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer to that question:

[RegEx for match/replacing JavaScript comments (both multiline and inline)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989315/regex-for-match-replacing-javascript-comments-both-multiline-and-inline)

Just use this RegEx instead:

```
(<![\-\-\s\w\>]*\-\-\>)
```