# RangError: too many arguments provided for a function call

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I got a nice solution to get HTML Comments from the HTML Node Tree

```
var findComments = function(el) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < el.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var node = el.childNodes[i];
        if (node.nodeType === 8) {
            arr.push(node);
        } else {
            arr.push.apply(arr, findComments(node));
        }
    }
    return arr;
};

var commentNodes = findComments(document);

// whatever you were going to do with the comment...
console.log(commentNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027830/is-it-possible-to-get-reference-to-comment-element-block-by-javascript).
Everything I did was adding this small loop to print out all the nodes.

```
var arr = [];
var findComments = function(el) {

    for (var i = 0; i < el.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var node = el.childNodes[i];
        if (node.nodeType === 8) {
            arr.push(node);
        } else {
            arr.push.apply(arr, findComments(node));
        }
    }
    return arr;
};
var commentNodes = findComments(document);

//I added this

for (var counter = arr.length; counter > 0; counter--) {
    console.log(commentNodes[counter].nodeValue);
}
```

I keep getting this Error Message:

> RangeError: too many arguments provided for a function call debugger
>   eval code:9:13

**EDIT:** i had a typo while pasting changed the code from i-- to counter--

Comment: In your added `for` loop, you use the variable `counter` in the test expression but then it ends with `i--`; should be `counter--`.

Comment: Also you moved the declaration of `arr` from outside the function to inside for some reason; probably not a great idea. *edit* in fact this is almost certainly what's causing your Range Error.

Comment: @choz the idea is probably to get a flat array; pushing the array will result in an array of arrays.

Comment: And you moved `arr` initialization outside loop, propably to use `arr.length` instead of `commentNodes.length`

Comment: @Pointy Ahh, nevermind my comment then. Probably in that line, OP shouldn't be pushing anything into the `arr` but rather just call `findComments(node)`. But am not sure as well 8/

Comment: Again OP, the problem is that you moved the declaration of `arr` from inside the function to outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `for` loop is not the only thing you changed (and see the other answer about fixing that loop too).  You also moved the declaration of `arr` from *inside* the function to outside, making `arr` relatively global.

Because of that, each recursive call to `findComments()` works on the *same array*, and the `.apply()` call pushes the entire contents back onto the end of the array every time. After a while, its length exceeds the limit of the runtime.

The original function posted at the top of your question has `arr` declared inside the function. Each recursive call therefore has its own local array to work with.  In a document with a **lot** of comment nodes, it could still get that Range Error however.

Answer (score 3):

see this comment [in MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) about the use of `apply` to merge arrays:

> Do not use this method if the second array (moreVegs in the example) is very large, because the maximum number of parameters that one function can take is limited in practice. See apply() for more details.

the other note from [apply page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

> But beware: in using apply this way, you run the risk of exceeding the JavaScript engine's argument length limit. The consequences of applying a function with too many arguments (think more than tens of thousands of arguments) vary across engines (JavaScriptCore has hard-coded argument limit of 65536), because the limit (indeed even the nature of any excessively-large-stack behavior) is unspecified. Some engines will throw an exception. More perniciously, others will arbitrarily limit the number of arguments actually passed to the applied function. To illustrate this latter case: if such an engine had a limit of four arguments (actual limits are of course significantly higher), it would be as if the arguments 5, 6, 2, 3 had been passed to apply in the examples above, rather than the full array.

Answer (score 2):

As the array start from index of 0, actually the last item in the array is `arr.length - 1`.

you can fix it by:

```
for (var counter = arr.length - 1; counter >= 0; counter--)
```

Notice I've added `arr.length -1` and `counter >= 0` as zero is the first index of the array.

Comment: This is true but it's not what's causing the `Range Error`.