# Scraping difficult table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to scrape a table from [here](https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019.html) for quite some time but have been unsuccessful. The table I am trying to scrape is titled "Team Per Game Stats". I am confident that once I am able to scrape one element of that table that I can iterate through the columns I want from the list and eventually end up with a pandas data frame.

Here is my code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# url that we are scraping
r = requests.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019.html')
# Lets look at what the request content looks like
print(r.content)

# use Beautifulsoup on content from request
c = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c)
print(soup)

# using prettify() in Beautiful soup indents HTML like it should be in the web page
# This can make reading the HTML a little be easier
print(soup.prettify())

# get elements within the 'main-content' tag
team_per_game = soup.find(id="all_team-stats-per_game")
print(team_per_game)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That page cheats, the HTML source for the tables is stored in *HTML comments*, that [Javascript then extracts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027830/is-it-possible-to-get-reference-to-comment-element-block-by-javascript) and turns back in to HTML...

Comment: Is this a preventative method to prevent scraping?

Comment: The more likely reason is to keep the tables from showing up in the Google results page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That webpage employs a trick to try to stop search engines and other automated web clients (including scrapers) from finding the table data: the tables are stored in HTML comments:

```html
<div id="all_team-stats-per_game" class="table_wrapper setup_commented commented">

<div class="section_heading">
  <span class="section_anchor" id="team-stats-per_game_link" data-label="Team Per Game Stats"></span><h2>Team Per Game Stats</h2>    <div class="section_heading_text">
      <ul> <li><small>* Playoff teams</small></li>
      </ul>
    </div>      
</div>
<div class="placeholder"></div>
<!--
   <div class="table_outer_container">
      <div class="overthrow table_container" id="div_team-stats-per_game">
  <table class="sortable stats_table" id="team-stats-per_game" data-cols-to-freeze=2><caption>Team Per Game Stats Table</caption>

...

</table>

      </div>
   </div>
-->
</div>
```

I note that the opening `div` has `setup_commented` and `commented` classes. Javascript code included in the page is then executed by your browser that then loads the text from those comments and replaces the `placeholder` div with the contents as new HTML for the browser to display.

You can extract the comment text here:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
placeholder = soup.select_one('#all_team-stats-per_game .placeholder')
comment = next(elem for elem in placeholder.next_siblings if isinstance(elem, Comment))
table_soup = BeautifulSoup(comment, 'lxml')
```

then continue to parse the table HTML.

This specific site has published both [terms of use](https://www.sports-reference.com/termsofuse.html), and [a page on data use](https://www.sports-reference.com/data_use.html) you should probably read if you are going to use their data. Specifically, their terms state, under section 6. *Site Content*:

> You may not frame, capture, harvest, or collect any part of the Site or Content without SRL's advance written consent.

Scraping the data would fall under that heading.

Comment: what does the word _next_ do in this context please?

Comment: @QHarr: it’s a [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next), it takes the next item from an iterator.  It is passed a generator expression that filters the `Element.next_siblings` iterator. I used this to skip the text node that directly follows the placeholder div

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete Martijn Pieters's answer (and without lxml)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
placeholder = soup.select_one('#all_team-stats-per_game .placeholder')
comment = next(elem for elem in placeholder.next_siblings if isinstance(elem, Comment))
table = BeautifulSoup(comment, 'html.parser')
rows = table.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cells = row.find_all('td')
    if cells:
        print([cell.text for cell in cells])
```

Partial output

```
[u'New Orleans Pelicans', u'71', u'240.0', u'43.6', u'91.7', u'.476', u'10.1', u'29.4', u'.344', u'33.5', u'62.4', u'.537', u'18.1', u'23.9', u'.760', u'11.0', u'36.0', u'47.0', u'27.0', u'7.5', u'5.5', u'14.5', u'21.4', u'115.5']
[u'Milwaukee Bucks*', u'69', u'241.1', u'43.3', u'90.8', u'.477', u'13.3', u'37.9', u'.351', u'30.0', u'52.9', u'.567', u'17.6', u'22.8', u'.773', u'9.3', u'40.1', u'49.4', u'26.0', u'7.4', u'6.0', u'14.0', u'19.8', u'117.6']
[u'Los Angeles Clippers', u'70', u'241.8', u'41.0', u'87.6', u'.469', u'9.8', u'25.2', u'.387', u'31.3', u'62.3', u'.502', u'22.8', u'28.8', u'.792', u'9.9', u'35.7', u'45.6', u'23.4', u'6.6', u'4.7', u'14.5', u'23.5', u'114.6']
```

Comment: Both are incredible answers. Thank you both!