# Is there a way to hide comments from inspect element?

Tags: html

I'm looking to hide some comments from the browser's inspector in my HTML document. I've thought about using php tags but i'm not sure if its frowned upon or if it'll affect the performace of my website. I don't want to do this for all comments just a certain few.
Are there any other ways to achieve this?

`<?php //comment ?>`

Comment: Why would you want to hide an HTML comment? There shouldn't be anything sensitive being sent to the browser. Anything sent can be viewed by one method or another.

Comment: related: [Is it possible to get reference to comment element/block by JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027830/is-it-possible-to-get-reference-to-comment-element-block-by-javascript)

You can then delete the nodes by using node.delete()

Comment: Nothing sensitive, I'd just like to add some comments at certain points in my html file but they look out of order in browser and it kinda bothers me.

Comment: I use asp server-comments. It works. No performance issues.

Comment: Comments in a PHP file wouldn't even be rendered to the client unless you  out put them as HTML